# No ValueError when assigning array with mismatched dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

Condider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
try:
    a[1,:] = (1,2,3,4)
    print "Value OK"
except ValueError:
    print "Value error"
```

On python 2.7.5 with numpy 1.7.1 this produces:

```
Value OK
```

On python 2.7.12 with numpy 1.11.0 this produces:

```
Value Error
```

I expect the latter because of the dimension mismatch. Is this just a bug in numpy 1.7.1 or should I not rely on the ValueError to be raised?

As a note: It looks like some sort of lazy evaluation issue. numpy 1.7.1 will raise the error eventually, but only when you try to access the array later.. can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: A possible match in 1.8.1 `gh-4024: Sequence assignment doesn’t raise exception on shape mismatch`..https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4024

Comment: @hpaulj Looks like the issue indeed. I'll accept it as the answer to my question if you provide it as such.